# Norms of elements in Artin-Schreier extensions

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, fields, norms, positive-characteristic

The following is claimed in the proof of Theorem 7.5 of Auslander, Goldman, "The Brauer group of a commutative ring":

> Let $k$ be a nonperfect field of positive characteristic $p$, let $K := k(x)$ be the function field in one variable, and let $L := K[y]/(y^{p}-y-x)$ be the Artin-Schreier extension of $K$ associated to $x \in K$. For any $c \in k^{\times} \setminus (k^{\times})^{p}$, there does not exist $\ell \in L$ such that $c = \mathrm{Nm}_{L/K}(\ell)$.

Why is this true?

*Remarks*:

1. An arbitrary element of $L$ is of the form $\ell = f(y)$ for some polynomial $$ f(T) = a_{0} + a_{1}T + \dotsb + a_{p-1}T^{p-1} $$ of degree at most $p-1$ with $a_{i} \in K$, and in this case we have norm $\mathrm{Nm}_{L/K}(\ell) = \prod_{i=0}^{p-1} f(y+i)$. However I am not sure if this product simplifies to a nice expression in $x$ and the $a_{i}$. For $p=2$ the product is $(a_{0}^{2} + xa_{1}^{2}) + a_{0}a_{1}$ and for $p=3$ the product is $(a_{0}^{3} + xa_{1}^{3} + x^{2}a_{2}^{3}) + (-a_{0}a_{1}^{2} - a_{0}^{2}a_{2} + a_{0}a_{2}^{2} - xa_{1}a_{2}^{2})$.
2. See also Example 11.6.9 of Fried, Jarden, "Field Arithmetic" which treats the $p=2$ case.

*Keywords*: Artin-Schreier extensions, Galois, cyclic, norm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's define the leading coefficient of a rational function to be the leading coefficient of the numerator over the leading coefficient of the denominator. We will show that the leading term of any norm is a $p$th power. It will follow that any norm that is a constant is a $p$th power.

Observe that $L$ is isomorphic to $k(y)$ . For $l(y)$ a rational function in $y$, the norm of $l$ is $l(y)l(y+1) \dots l(y+p-1)$, which are all rational functions with the same leading term, so the leading term of their product is the $p$th power of the leading term of $y$. Then we can write it as a rational function in $x$ by the substitution $y^p-y=x$, which does not affect the leading term, so the leading term is a $p$th power, as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the edit (I was getting confused by the formal Laurent series argument).

Comment: … did you mean *over* the leading coefficient of the denominator?